# Sass: how to get a filesystem's absolute path of current .sass file?

Tags: sass

Something like `@current_file_path()` which returns actual path of the file in the file system?

---

My actual problem is the following.

I have a submodule with it's own `.scss` file and related images.

The submodule's styles are included in a common module's file which is not in the same directory (actually it's in the parent directory) like this:

```
@include "submodule/_style";
```

In the submodule's file I want to write like that:

```
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
```

But I can't. Because all the paths are relative to the common module file, as only it is compiled into final CSS, not the current submodule file. So I have to do like this:

```
$submodule-dir: "submodule";
background-image: url("$submodule-dir/image.jpg");
```

So I want to make a function which calculates `$submodule-dir` automatically for the current file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is no function in sass that gets the current file path.

Its follows normal css syntax. 
So you have to define the path in your submodeles.
But we can create a function to make it easier for us:

Like this:

```
$currentModule: "../submodule/image/";

@function setUrl($file) {
  @return url($currentModule + $file);
}

.main {
  background-image: setUrl("file.jpg");
}
```